# C# Winform finding coordinates of a chart

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm new to C#. I'm trying to build an application, which represents line charts for different data series. When I run the application, it paints all the charts, So there is a scroll bar, because not all the charts may be contained on a screen.
In addition I have a tree-view with the names of each series.
I want to give this functionality to the tree-view:
When I click on a node within a tree, the corresponding chart to this node should appear on the screen. That means, the scroll bar should be scrolled to a specific position, where the desired chart is located.
Any ideas how can I do it? How to get the coordinates of the chart relative to the Form.

I paint the charts at tableLayoutPanel.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                    for (int j = 0; j < Red_charts.Count; j++)
                    {
                        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Red_charts.ElementAt(j));
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    for (int j = 0; j < Yellow_charts.Count; j++)
                    {
                        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Yellow_charts.ElementAt(j));
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    for (int j = 0; j < Green_charts.Count; j++)
                    {
                        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Green_charts.ElementAt(j));
                    }
                    break;
            }//switch
        }//for 3 colors
```

This is how the charts are added.

Comment: Could you post your code please?  That would allow us to help you better

Comment: What part of the code would be helpful? The program is a bit long

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the tableLayoutPanel.ScrollControlIntoView property.
Problem solved. Thanks.